# I'm getting a "connection attempt failed" while trying to create a database/table on a mySQL server on RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a mySQL server on RDS and I'm trying to create a database on it. I provided the correct username and password, I made it publicly accessible, the security group is allowing all traffic on all ports and I'm still getting connection failed.

Here's what I'm trying to run in my code

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="I entered my RDS endpoint here",
  user="admin",
  password="admin123"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE test")
```

And here's the error I received

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'The Endpoint to my RDS:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

I'm not sure what else to try to create a database on RDS

Comment: You have to provide more details. Is your RDS in a public subnet? what exactly are its SGs or network ACLs?

Comment: @Marcin I chose to make it publicly accessible and the subnet it's in has two inbound rules:

1. It says Rule "100" and allows all traffic
2. Says Rule "*" and denies all traffic

The subnet has an Internet Gateway, so I'm not sure if the current inbound rules are what's messing it up

Comment: Making RDS "publicly accessible" is not enough to make it actually "publicly accessible". What is your VPC setup? Which subnet is your RDS in?